# My display switches off, keyboard stops working, but I can SSH

Tags: keyboard, radeon, crash, gpu

The amount of time varies, from about 1 minute in, to 20, or sometimes never. My screen will go black, and say No Signal, and my keyboard and mouse will stop working. My computer is still on, the disk light still flashes, and I can SSH in from my phone. Additionally, any media playing continues until it ends, but if I'm listening to music in totem, it won't loop after it finishes.

#### SSHing in

First I thought it was my GPU, so I tried `radeontop`. It reports stupid values like 20,000% of video ram used. It doesn't matter whether I run it before or after the "crash", it'll still show stupid high percentages once it "crashes".

I can see programs I have been running are still open, because I can get their PIDs.

`sudo restart` won't restart my computer. `sudo service gdm restart` doesn't seem to do anything. My keyboard doesn't have a SysRQ key so I can't REISUB.

#### Times when it happened

- When I click on a link on Firefox
- If I open VS Code
- i forgor
- Just randomly, like if my screen is locked or something

EDIT:

```
me@my computer:~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] [1002:67df] (rev e7)
me@my computer:~$ glxinfo -B | grep -i '\(direct rendering\|opengl\|profile\)' 
direct rendering: Yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: AMD
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon RX 580 Series (POLARIS10, DRM 3.41.0, 5.13.0-52-generic, LLVM 12.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
me@my computer:~$ sudo env X -version
[sudo] password for me: 

X.Org X Server 1.20.13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: linux Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux my computer 5.13.0-52-generic #59~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 16 21:21:28 UTC 2022 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-52-generic root=UUID=facdf251-6fa6-469a-bdca-1647eabc527f ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 14 December 2021  02:14:13PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
me@my computer:~$ inxi -F

Command 'inxi' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install inxi

me@my computer:~$ sudo apt install inxi
ok
me@my computer:~$ inxi -F
System:
  Host: my computer Kernel: 5.13.0-52-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 
  Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: ROG STRIX B450-F GAMING v: Rev 1.xx 
  serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 3103 
  date: 06/17/2020 
Battery:
  ID-1: hidpp_battery_0 charge: N/A condition: N/A 
CPU:
  Topology: 6-Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 2600X bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  Speed: 2055 MHz min/max: 2200/3600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2044 2: 1972 
  3: 2187 4: 2190 5: 2191 6: 2192 7: 2184 8: 2166 9: 2122 10: 1884 11: 2196 
  12: 2191 
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] 
  driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: amdgpu 
  resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon RX 580 Series (POLARIS10 DRM 3.41.0 
  5.13.0-52-generic LLVM 12.0.0) 
  v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6 
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] 
  driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: AMD Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.13.0-52-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel I211 Gigabit Network driver: igb 
  IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: 24:4b:fe:e0:62:c0 
  Device-2: Ralink RT5572 Wireless Adapter type: USB driver: rt2800usb 
  IF: wlxe8de27a1d54e state: up mac: e8:de:27:a1:d5:4e 
  IF-ID-1: virbr0 state: down mac: 52:54:00:2f:c9:ac 
  IF-ID-2: virbr0-nic state: down mac: 52:54:00:2f:c9:ac 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 2.73 TiB used: 1.06 TiB (38.7%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: SSD 860 EVO 1TB size: 931.51 GiB 
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Samsung model: SSD 870 EVO 2TB size: 1.82 TiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 915.40 GiB used: 510.45 GiB (55.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 35.4 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 50 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: amdgpu fan: 3 
Info:
  Processes: 458 Uptime: 2h 43m Memory: 15.55 GiB used: 6.03 GiB (38.8%) 
  Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
me@my computer:~$ uname -r
5.13.0-52-generic
```

Comment: can you check *regular* RAM used?

Comment: What should I do? SSH in and run top, and wait for it to "crash"?

Comment: I guess so, if it happens frequently enough that it's feasible it could be helpful to know. Also a lot of keyboards use different keys/key combinations for SysRq, see [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Commands) which lists a lot of common combinations

Comment: If you'r able to, unplug the video card and use mother board dsiplay's chipset.
If it's right then you know what you have to change...

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll have to provide a lot more info about your HW & SW e.g.

```
LANG=C lspci -nn | grep VGA  # might require installing pciutils
LANG=C glxinfo -B | grep -i '\(direct rendering\|opengl\|profile\)' 
sudo env LANG=C X -version
inxi -F
uname -r
```

Second it could be anything. For example I once had the same symptoms and it was a HW error due to a bad capacitor causing the motherboard to not deliver enough power to the GPU; thus it would freeze either randomly or when it got stressed.

Also if it's a discrete GPU, check your GPU is properly plugged directly to the PSU if it has such PCIE connectors. Sometimes the builder forgets to plug it and the system still boots (or it's plugged but loose).

You should also run a memtest to discard RAM problems.

Now, assuming it's a SW problem, since you can SSH into the machine, once this problem happens see the output of:

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
cat /var/log/syslog
cat /var/log/kern.log
```

Usually the error message will be in there.

> sudo restart won't restart my computer

Try `sudo shutdown -r now` instead

Last but not least, sometimes the problem is caused by unstable power changes. Try setting [power_dpm_state](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.20/gpu/amdgpu.html#power-dpm-state) or [power-dpm-force-performance-level](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.20/gpu/amdgpu.html#power-dpm-force-performance-level) (depending on your machine) to always max power (and also try always min power)

## Update

You posted your system specs.

Your GPU (+ Mesa driver) is a very stable one in Ubuntu 20.04; so I now doubt that is the problem now (unless it's HW).

### Things to look for:

- Your AMD GPU thermals are too high for idle (50°C). Check the thermals when on load and check the fan is spinning. It may be seriously overheating.

  - For reference mine is at 32°C while I'm typing in askubuntu (room temp: 19°C) using Chrome.
- As previously mentioned, check other Kernel versions. It may have been a temporary regression (this happens sometimes). Also try the 5.4.x line of kernels.
- Ryzen 5 2600 [is known](https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/ryzen-5-2600-freezes-minutes-after-booting-linux/td-p/133458) for [firmware bugs](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196683#c318) related to C states that freeze on Linux. A BIOS update often fixes it; otherwise try booting the kernel params `idle=nomwait rcu_nocbs=0-11` and maybe `processor.max_cstate=5`. If your BIOS is up to date, then you may only need to add `acpi_osi=Linux` to your boot params

  - Warning: Updating a BIOS improperly can brick your motherboard unless you have specialized tools to recover it or the motherboard has a BIOS recover functionality (some models do, specially the expensive ones)
  - Warning 2: You should first determine it's not a HW problem. For example if the RAM is bad (run a memtest first), you **really** don't want to upgrade the BIOS while the RAM (or any other component) is malfunctioning as it could corrupt or interrupt the upgrade process
  - In very rare cases, a BIOS upgrade can cause your GPU to no longer work on that motherboard if you later enable Secure Boot after the BIOS upgrade; even if that GPU previously worked with Secure Boot enabled before the upgrade ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQG153s1NIM)). An acquaintance of mine has had this problem with an AMD GPU.
- The disks may be bad. Look in `sudo dmesg` for SATA errors. Also check the outputs of `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda` and `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb` (or check them in `gnome-disks` -> SMART Data & Self-Tests).

  - Both disks should say `SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED`
  - If the disks are 'failing', it could be that the problem is the SATA cable (and obviously, backup everything ASAP).
- The previous tips still apply (i.e. it could be a failing PSU: check for [bad caps](https://www.badcaps.net/index.php?s=27f847498526069588997a55957eedae&pageid=identity), inspect the logs, run a memtest to discard RAM problems)

Comment: It's stopped happening (i guess the issue was scared of being fixed lol) but here's the info:

Comment: `lspci` : `08:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] [1002:67df] (rev e7)`

Comment: this is a lot of information, i'll edit it into the question

Comment: Thanks! Posted an update / reply.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about GPU temp, I think my idle temp should be about 30° but it just keeps heating up... I don't know why it's doing that but I'm going to install radeon-profile to see what that does

Comment: Yep, using custom curve on radeon-profile has helped as the BIOS one is for only CPU